# report preview flashes and disappears

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

When i'm trying to preview the data in IReports by clicking the preview tab, it is just flashing and going back, but i'm unable to see the data.

Below is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report5" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b8a981bc-ae9b-4fcf-8400-f9ecea0567f2">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
   `Date assigned` AS Date_assigned,
   Units,
   `Assigned to PS` AS Assigned_to_PS
FROM
   [Sheet1$]
]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Date_assigned" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="Units" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Assigned_to_PS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Date_assigned">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date_assigned}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement uuid="db476b5b-d93f-4819-a8f6-174bfc88c9b7" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="125"/>
                <rowGroup name="Date_assigned" width="70" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.util.Date">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date_assigned}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="cb26a0e2-7fa8-4124-be7f-f91e491801f7" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="25"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Date_assigned}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="c97deff9-a499-4330-aa84-baf20315a1de" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="25"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total Date_assigned]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="Assigned_to_PS" height="30" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Assigned_to_PS}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="7e26e7de-b54f-4490-9ea1-b087247e9c06" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Assigned_to_PS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="86c2ceb5-b2d2-4cc7-953e-0c039e807ec1" x="86" y="0" width="50" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total Assigned_to_PS]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="UnitssMeasure" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Unitss}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="38">
                    <cellContents>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="7729498a-0309-4052-a002-e58592da972b" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{UnitssMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="61" rowTotalGroup="Date_assigned">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="35ba6c60-5505-4eba-be7b-8627a9516c7d" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{UnitssMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="136" height="38" columnTotalGroup="Assigned_to_PS">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="c260e58c-5377-4582-bdfe-59a3f337feee" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="86" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{UnitssMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="136" height="61" rowTotalGroup="Date_assigned" columnTotalGroup="Assigned_to_PS">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="468233cd-75a6-4278-ba3f-de35032a5459" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="86" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{UnitssMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This is actually a pivot table from excel data source, please let me know how do i preview it. And also i'm not getting any errors.

expected output is

```
          Amreen    Anirudh Anand   Total
7/1/2013    158                      158
7/2/2013    23                        23
7/3/2013    152      748             900
7/4/2013                
7/5/2013                
7/6/2013    435                      435
7/7/2013    170                      170
7/8/2013    66                        66
7/9/2013    33               33       66
Total      1037      748     33     1818
```

Thanks

Comment: From where are you getting `Total Date_assigned` ? Can you explain ?

Comment: From my excel @Kalathoki

Comment: @user2423959 Your templates contains a lot of mistakes: 1) `<measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Unitss}]]></measureExpression>` - expression is wrong, 2) you should place crosstab to another band, for example to *Summary* band, 3) probably the dataset does not set in right way.  You should post the screenshot of *TO-BE* report and the working *jrxml* file. The one that you have posted does not even compiling

Comment: @user2423959 Try to put the crosstab at the *Summary* band. It works for me in this case (after fixing `measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Unitss}]]></measureExpression>` to `measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Units}]]></measureExpression>`)

Comment: Hi @AlexK Thanks for response i've made thae changes that you mentioned abobe but the data is still flashing. i've moved the data to summary band. and i use ireports, here when i click on preview, this happens. :-( i 've updated my question with o/p expected. i've actually tried created the cross tab from this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goMekbmIG2Y